# Ubuntu 16.04 Qualcomm AR9287 failed to initialize device

Tags: 16.04, ath9k

Basically, computer recognizes the card, but nothing wireless related seems to work. It doesn't show up in Network. I also tried this card in my windows box where it works perfectly.

Output of `dmesg`

```
[    3.651544] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[    3.651545] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[    3.651546] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[    3.651546] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[    3.651547] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[    3.651547] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[    3.651571] nommu_map_single: overflow 7f8d34040+1926 of device mask ffffffff
[    3.651596] ath: phy0: dma_mapping_error() on RX init
[    3.651648] ath9k 0000:21:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[    3.651744] ath9k: probe of 0000:21:00.0 failed with error -12
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:21:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7500000-f750ffff
```

`uname -r`:

```
4.10.1-041001-generic
```

edit:

output from diagnostic script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 02 Jun 2017 16:27 PDT -0700

Booted last: 02 Jun 2017 00:00 PDT -0700

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.1-041001-generic #201702260735 SMP Sun Feb 26 12:36:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 unknown unknown GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

1e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8677]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

21:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002e] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:30a4]
    Kernel modules: ath9k

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c07e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
video                  40960  1 asus_wmi
ath9k                 147456  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
mac80211              782336  1 ath9k
cfg80211              602112  4 mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
wmi                    16384  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp30s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp30s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.2.6  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2614:c730:926a:8d88/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11171754 (11.1 MB)  TX bytes:934886 (934.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:132298 (132.2 KB)  TX bytes:132298 (132.2 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp30s0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp30s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp30s0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp30s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1032     1  0 16:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp30s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp30s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.2/0000:1d:00.0/0000:1e:00.0/net/enp30s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp30s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d36c51b9-7c50-38a0-92ee-5e74abfd62b0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d36c51b9-7c50-38a0-92ee-5e74abfd62b0 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.2.6/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.2.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        server_name = Jacobs-MacBook-Pro.local
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1496531409
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 85536
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.2.6
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       routers = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.2.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.2.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.2.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.2.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::2614:c730:926a:8d88/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Los_Angeles (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp30s0   no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp30s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.1-041001-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     8D9A8DB09580DED6F4121A4
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.1-041001-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.1-041001-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     4A717CCB1446CC9DB8FCEC7
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.1-041001-generic SMP mod_unload 

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.1-041001-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     41F2314E0EE763A827038D0
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.1-041001-generic SMP mod_unload 

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.1-041001-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     4B8612B6FF71DD27AE8CE67
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.1-041001-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.1-041001-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     E52821BAF5B1A86DD9B493B
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.1-041001-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.1-041001-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     069B9FECEE6C93D61A92E18
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.1-041001-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
led_active_high: -1
nohwcrypt: 1
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    3.628167] ath9k 0000:21:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.717711] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8348
[    3.717712] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[    3.717713] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[    3.717713] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3a
[    3.717714] ath: Country alpha2 being used: US
[    3.717714] ath: Regpair used: 0x3a
[    3.717784] ath: phy0: dma_mapping_error() on RX init
[    3.717840] ath9k 0000:21:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[    3.717941] ath9k: probe of 0000:21:00.0 failed with error -12
[    4.529809] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp30s0: link is not ready
[    4.556525] r8169 0000:1e:00.0 enp30s0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[    4.556611] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp30s0: link is not ready
[    8.589885] r8169 0000:1e:00.0 enp30s0: link up
[    8.589895] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp30s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Hi David, I just edited my post! Also if this is relevant, I tried it in my windows box and it worked perfectly out of the box, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the card.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found this page to be useful https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314693

I entered in the terminal:

```
echo ath9k | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/ath9k.conf
```

Then restart

Comment: This didn't work for me. It seems like it's not an issue with attempting to load on boot, but when it tries to load something fails.